# Building an index: Copies or pointers?

Tags: c++, data-structures, indexing

I have a data structure that stores ... well, data. Now, I need to access various pieces of data in slightly different manner, so I'm essentially building an in-memory index. But I'm wondering: should the index hold pointers or copies?

To elaborate, say I have

```
class Widget
{
    // Ways to access the list of gears...
private:
    std::list<Gears> m_gears;
};
```

Now, I have two `Widget`s, and there exists between these two a mapping between their `Gear`s. Currently, this is

```
boost::unordered_map<Gear, Gear>
```

but `Gear` is a fairly hefty class, and I feel like making so many copies is poor design. I could store a pointer, but then the mapping is only valid for the lifetime of the corresponding `Widget`s, and you start getting `->`s... (And if that `std::list` ever changes to a `std::vector`, it gets more complex...)

Pertaining to the copies, it's actually slightly worse: There's two `boost::unordered_map`s, one for each direction. So, for each `Gear`, I'm making up to 2 copies of it.

Alternatively, I could put the index inside the `Widget` class, but I feel like this violates the responsibilities of the `Widget` class.

Comment: Doesn't boost have a multi-index container?

Answer (score 0):

You might try Boost Pointer Container Library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html

I think it addresses exactly the problem you are facing.

Comment: My understanding of the Boost Pointer Containers is that they owned the objects inserted into them. My objects are actually on the stack, and thus, do not need `delete` called on them. I might still look into this to see if there's a way to use it without it deleting its contents.

Answer (score 0):

Could you store all gears in one place, like statically in the gears class, and then have each mapping AND widget store only the reference/index to it?

You would have to keep track of references to each gear so you know when you can dispose them, but that should be easy enough.

Comment: This sounds like a flyweight -- is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, that sounds like what I was describing. (Thank you, I had not heard the term before.) Since you have, does it not solve your problem?